How to add Crashlytics in iOS flutter app?
I have followed many documents still couldn't find how to add crashlytics? and in console i need to see the list of crashes,
I have followed this to add crashlytics,
import 'package:firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics.dart';

and added package
Firebase_ios_sdk
this document I Have followed
Please help me to add a crashlytics with detailed information,

Please detail all the steps you have performed, and where relevant, share the necessary code/files. Without them, it will be hard for anyone to help you.

Check now and please check what i'm missing as result today i have to complete this.

You have added a link, which doesn't help anyone in understand what exactly exists in your code.

In simulator debugging crashlytics won't work, in physical device it will work, and this has been solved

You have to add this package to your project and then follow the documentation steps here.
